# How pthread_exit() and pthread_cancel() calls cleanup routine in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have observed while learning concept about pthread_cleanup_push, that pthread_exit() and pthread_cancel() impact on pthread_cleanup_pop() in different ways. Below is the code sample.

```
void push_routine_1(void * arg) {
    printf(" Push Routine 1\n");
}

void push_routine_2(void * arg) {
    printf(" Push Routine 2\n");
}

void push_routine_3(void * arg) {
    printf(" Push Routine 3\n");
}

void push_routine_4(void * arg) {
    printf(" Push Routine 4\n");
}

void * thread_routine(void * arg) {
    pthread_cleanup_push(push_routine_1, NULL);
    pthread_cleanup_push(push_routine_2, NULL);
    pthread_cleanup_push(push_routine_3, NULL);
    pthread_cleanup_push(push_routine_4, NULL);

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
}
```

Above program gives such output:

```
Push Routine 4
Push Routine 3 
Push Routine 2 
Push Routine 1
```

While using `pthread_cancel(pthread_self())` instead of `pthread_exit(NULL)`, gives output as below

```
Push Routine 3 
Push Routine 2 
Push Routine 1
```

What is the reason behind not executing `push_routine_4()` while using `pthread_cancel()`?

Comment: The above code does not print anything since it's missing a main function

Comment: "what is the reason ..." -- there is a bug elsewhere in your program, or a bug in your pthread implementation. But you didn't supply a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and didn't tell us which OS, which version of libpthread, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you may assume that `pthread_cancel(pthread_self())` is exactly the same as `pthread_exit(NULL)`.

POSIX does not tell me what to expect `pthread_cancel(pthread_self())` to do.  But I note that it says:

> 2.9.5 Thread Cancellation
>
> The thread cancellation mechanism allows a thread to terminate the execution of any other thread in the process in a controlled manner.

where "any **other** thread" does make me wonder.  But I don't think that's the issue.

The default 'cancelability type' is PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED.  So, `pthread_cancel()` will not take effect until the next 'Cancellation Point' in the cancelled thread.  So your code will continue in to the first `pthread_cleanup_pop(1)`, which is *not* a 'Cancellation Point', which will then `printf(" Push Routine 4\n")`, which *may be* a 'Cancellation Point'.

I adjusted your code as follows:

```
static volatile unsigned step ;

void push_routine_1(void * arg) {
  step += 10 ;
  printf(" Push Routine 1 -- %u\n", step);
  step += 10 ;
}

void push_routine_2(void * arg) {
  step += 100 ;
  printf(" Push Routine 2 -- %u\n", step);
  step += 100 ;
}

void push_routine_3(void * arg) {
  step += 1000 ;
  printf(" Push Routine 3 -- %u\n", step);
  step += 1000 ;
}

void push_routine_4(void * arg) {
  step += 10000 ;
  printf(" Push Routine 4 -- %u\n", step);
  step += 10000 ;
}

void * thread_routine(void * arg)
{
  unsigned frag = *(unsigned*)arg ;

  printf("Start %u\n", frag) ;

  step = 0 ;
  pthread_cleanup_push(push_routine_1, NULL); step += 10 ;
  pthread_cleanup_push(push_routine_2, NULL); step += 100;
  pthread_cleanup_push(push_routine_3, NULL); step += 1000 ;
  pthread_cleanup_push(push_routine_4, NULL); step += 10000 ;

  step++ ;
  if (frag == 0)
    pthread_exit(NULL) ;        // 11111
  else
    pthread_cancel(pthread_self()) ;

  step++ ;                      // 11112

  if (frag == 2)
    printf(" Continue %u\n", step) ;

  step++ ;                      // 11113
  pthread_cleanup_pop(1);       // (4)
  step++ ;                      // xxxx4
  pthread_cleanup_pop(1);       // (3)
  step++ ;                      // xxxx5
  pthread_cleanup_pop(1);       // (2)
  step++ ;                      // xxxx6
  pthread_cleanup_pop(1);       // (1)
  step++ ;                      // xxxx7
}

int
main(Unused int argc, Unused char* argv[])
{
  unsigned frag ;

  for (frag = 0 ; frag < 3 ; ++frag)
    {
      pthread_t thr ;

      pthread_create(&thr, NULL, thread_routine, &frag) ;
      pthread_join(thr, NULL) ;

      printf(" Finally %u\n", step) ;
    } ;

  return 0 ;
}
```

And the result was:

```
Start 0
 Push Routine 4 -- 21111
 Push Routine 3 -- 32111
 Push Routine 2 -- 33211
 Push Routine 1 -- 33321
 Finally 33331
Start 1
 Push Routine 4 -- 21113
 Push Routine 3 -- 22113
 Push Routine 2 -- 23213
 Push Routine 1 -- 23323
 Finally 23333
Start 2
 Continue 11112
 Push Routine 4 -- 21112
 Push Routine 3 -- 32112
 Push Routine 2 -- 33212
 Push Routine 1 -- 33322
 Finally 33332
```

So for:

- 'Start 0' we see that (as expected) the thread proceeds no further than `pthread_exit(NULL)`.
- 'Start 1' we see that the thread gets to `pthread_cleanup_pop(1); // (4)`, but `push_routine_4()` does *not* get past the `printf()`.

  I believe this shows that the cancellation process starts once that `printf()` completes.
- 'Start 2' we see that `push_routine_4()` is invoked after the `printf(" Continue %u\n", step)`, and before the `step++` which follows it.

  I believe this shows that the cancellation process starts once that `printf(" Continue ...)` completes.

On my machine, Linux 5.6.8 running glibc 2.30, it appears that `printf()` is a 'Cancellation Point', after the function completes.  The effect you get suggests perhaps `printf()` is a 'Cancellation Point' before it prints anything ?  [Or there is some other reason the `printf()` in `push_routine_4()` does not produce any output.]